# facebook is not recognizing my meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
        <title></title>
            <meta property="og:title" content="Katha Screenplay Darsakatvam (KSD) Appalaraju "/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://reviewumpire.com/movies/54-katha-screenplay-darsakatvam-ksd-appalaraju-"/>

        <meta property="og:image" content="http://reviewumpire.com/images/uploads/movie/vertical/54/vert.jpg"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="ReviewUmpire"/>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="162180660488445" />
        <meta property="fb:admins" content="57728908711" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="23% scored on reveiwumpire."/>

        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="RXjWilEYk0eC_6ulYSV_AaFVSQe8nHI6Zw4_W9dVR5I" />
        <script src="/javascripts/vendor/jquery.min.js?1306239220" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/vendor/quote.rotator.js?1306239220" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/javascripts/vendor/scroll.js?1306239220" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/vendor/rails.js?1306239220" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1306239220" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/stylesheets/compiled/grid.css?1306239220" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/stylesheets/compiled/text.css?1306239220" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:regular,bold&amp;subset=greek,latin" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&amp;subset=greek,latin" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="ZrmCr3Qg7dNgPynFSSyFEHNaSpOUMYNEput1oUcyMIE="/>
      </head>
```

when i use facebook lint
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint
it is not detecting any of my facebook tags

```
Warning
Required Property Missing   og:title is required
Required Property Missing   og:type is required
Required Property Missing   og:image is required
Required Property Missing   og:url is required
```

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer. Did you identify the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The URL you've specified at the `og:url` meta tag contains an invalid `fb:admin`. Please update it with a valid admin ID and try again.

See Lint information at the [Facebook Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Freviewumpire.com%2Fmovies%2F54-katha-screenplay-darsakatvam-ksd-appalaraju-)

> Object at URL "http://reviewumpire.com/movies/54-katha-screenplay-darsakatvam-ksd-appalaraju-" of type "website" is invalid because the given value "57728908711" for property "fb:admins" could not be parsed as type "fbid". Invalid Admins -> The fb:admins field contained some invalid ids, namely 57728908711

Comment: This is the link that I needed. I needed to re-scrape the OG object and not rescrape the OG tags itself.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and what I found out was that Facebook recognizes

```
AddMetaData("og:url", "yourURL")
```

and then goes to yourURL to get the other tag info like `og:title`...etc

Comment: In my experience most open graph metadata problems are either this (og:url points to a page which is missing metadata) or the page is returning different HTML to the Facebook crawler than is returned to regular browsers

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question but I can't really see the answer that I find - just remove slash (/) at the end of facebook meta code.

So Facebook create wrong code if you not using right DOCTYPE:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Katha Screenplay Darsakatvam (KSD) Appalaraju "/>
```

right is:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Katha Screenplay Darsakatvam (KSD) Appalaraju ">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the namespace definitions
`xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"`
`xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"`

Edit:
`<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
    xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
    lang="en" dir="ltr">`

Comment: You still need the original namespace definition as well.

Comment: can you paste whole line so that i can try.

Comment: still failing please look below url http://reviewumpire.com/movies/54-katha-screenplay-darsakatvam-ksd-appalaraju-

Comment: i am using javascript sdk to generate the like button

Comment: You are missing the DOCTYPE definition in the source code on the actual page... run your page through the validator http://validator.w3.org

Comment: You need something like this...
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

I checked out my code and discovered that i was outputting some data before the  tags. This caused the facebook parser to mess up and as soon as i removed the html from outside those tags it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP response headers your server is sending out for that page.

If the Content-Length field is missing then that is your problem. In my experience, Facebook will not parse your page if that field is missing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was because I had a 302 Redirect to get to the actual page with the OG meta tags. My guess would be that the Facebook crawler doesn't follow redirects so you have to make sure you're returning a 200 on the first request.

Answer (score 0):

Might also be wrong encoded double quotes in the meta tags, if e.g. you have copied the code from a browser into your editor.

I found a huge number of bugs in my pages markup by using the linter at
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Down below is a function: "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" which is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="162180660488445" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="57728908711" />
```

and use this, to test your url and error info

> http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

What we noticed is that the facebook crawler is willing to follow redirects in the og:image url but the facebook client does not. Take this example.

Try posting the following link into facebook. If facebook has seen the url before, their crawler will have properly cached the image. If it hasn't, it will not. To simulate this behavior, put a random string into the ref parameter of the url below.

http://www.blipboard.com/4fac51e571272e0100000015?ref=1

If you try to post this url (with the random id inserted) it will fail to show the correct image the first time. If you then reload the facebook page and try to post again, this time it will work.

The meta-tag is the following (which requires a redirect):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graph.facebook.com/1000484548/picture?type=large" />
```

The best explanation I have for this is that the facebook client code doesn't follow redirects but the crawler does (as does the debugger)