# Facebook like button and white logo

Tags: html, css, facebook

When I click on the fb "like" button on my website, the result does not look good on facebook. The picture displayed on FB is the logo of the website, unfortunately my logo is white, so white logo on white background does not look good. Is there a way to tell facebook to display an other image instead? I tried meta property="og:image but without success. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you're setting the `meta`?

Comment: This is typically why most companies have two logos, one being the inverse of another. For example, twitter has a white bird, and a blue bird. For this exact scenario.

Comment: hi - i have updated the url in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Facebook Linter to see the results Facebook is pulling from your site's og-meta tags. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Whenever I change any of the values for one of my sites, I use this tool to validate what can be seen on FB, and it also accelerates updating the open graph, because sometimes, results are not immediately pulled from your site when updated because older values reside in the cache.

Comment: Thanks - this is odd, looks like fb doesnt recognise the tags (msg: the 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided...). Have updated the url of my website in my initial post.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109973/facebook-is-not-recognizing-my-meta-tags